# NullPointerException when using DAO class

Tags: java

I tried out DAO Pattern after reading 
http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/DataAccessObject.html
but I get NullPointerException when I run the servlet

**DAOFactory**

```
package dao;
import java.sql.SQLException;
public abstract class DAOFactory {
// List of DAO types supported by the factory
public static final int MYSQL = 1;

public abstract UserDAO getUserDAO() throws SQLException;

public static DAOFactory getDAOFactory(int whichFactory) {

switch (whichFactory) {
  case MYSQL: 
      return new MySQLDAOFactory();
  default        : 
      return null;
}
}
}
```

**MySQLDAOFactory**

```
package dao;
import java.sql.*;
public class MySQLDAOFactory extends DAOFactory {

public MySQLDAOFactory() {
}
public static final String DRIVER="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
public static final String DBURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/musicompany";

public static Connection createConnection() {
    Connection conn=null;
    try{
        Class.forName(DRIVER);
        conn =  DriverManager.getConnection(DBURL,"root","toor");
    }catch(Exception e){}
    return conn;
}
public UserDAO getUserDAO() throws SQLException{
    return new MySQLUserDAO();
}
}
```

**MySQLUserDAO**

```
package dao;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import model.User;

public class MySQLUserDAO implements UserDAO {

Connection conn=null;
Statement s=null;
public MySQLUserDAO() throws SQLException{
    conn = MySQLDAOFactory.createConnection();
    s = conn.createStatement();
}

public int insertUser(String fname, String lname) 
{
    try{
    //code to insertUser
    }catch(Exception e){}
    return key;
}


public ArrayList<User> selectUsers() {
    ResultSet rs=null;
    ArrayList customerList=null;
    try{
        rs =s.executeQuery("select * from users");
        customerList = new ArrayList<User>();
        while(rs.next())
        {
            customerList.add(new User(rs.getString("name"), rs.getString("pass"), rs.getInt("type"), rs.getString("email")));
        }
        return customerList;
    }catch(Exception e){}
    return customerList;
}
}
```

**UserDAO**

```
package dao;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import model.User;

public interface UserDAO {
public int insertUser(String fname, String lname);
public ArrayList<User> selectUsers();
}
```

**model.User.java**

This class has the following fields and the corresponding accessor methods.

```
String name;
String pass;
short type;
String email;
```

**My Servlet file**

```
public class AddRetrieve extends HttpServlet {
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException{
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        // create the required DAO Factory
        DAOFactory factoryObj = DAOFactory.getDAOFactory(DAOFactory.MYSQL);

        // Create a DAO
        UserDAO custDAO = factoryObj.getUserDAO();

        // print existing users
        ArrayList list = custDAO.selectUsers();
        Iterator i = list.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext())
        {
            User o = (User)i.next();
            out.println(o.getName());
        }

    } catch(Exception e)
    {
        out.println(e);
    }
    finally {            
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is my SQL table- "users"                                        name varchar(10);   
pass varchar(10);   
type tinyint(4);
email varchar(45);   
id int(11) PRI auto_increment;

Comment: You're better off learning something like Spring than trying to digest Sun's writings on J2EE patterns.  Really.  Your life will be easier and your code, cleaner.

Comment: Where are you getting the nullpointerexception in your servlet?

Comment: @Paul, It's interesting to work without using Frameworks, Also this is not for a real time project.

Comment: @Kal, Stack trace points to MySQLUserDAO class and line                `s = conn.createStatement()`

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with Java EE, design patterns nor Servlets. You got an trivial exception of the `java.lang` package which is just basic Java. I've removed the irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Stack trace points to MySQLUserDAO class and line `s = conn.createStatement()`*

So, the `conn` is `null`.

Let's look how you're creating the `conn`:

```
public static Connection createConnection() {
    Connection conn=null;
    try{
        Class.forName(DRIVER);
        conn =  DriverManager.getConnection(DBURL,"root","toor");
    }catch(Exception e){}
    return conn;
}
```

So, you're ignoring any exception thrown and returning a `null` connection instead of throwing an exception so that the code immediately stops.

Your technical problem is caused by the driver apparently not being in the classpath and your real design problem is you should never ignore exceptions unless you're 100% sure that it's safe to continue the code flow.

It's by the way unnecessary to load the driver *everytime*. Just load it once on class' initialization.

Rewrite that piece as follows:

```
static {
    try{
        Class.forName(DRIVER);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError("Driver " + DRIVER + " missing in classpath", e);
    }
}

public static Connection createConnection() throws SQLException {
    return DriverManager.getConnection(DBURL, "root", "toor");
}
```

Comment: +1 for not catching exceptions and just continuing on. This comes up surprisingly often.

Comment: @BalusC,                                                         Thanks. And you are right. It was a driver problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with this kind of Factory

**MySqlDAOFactory**

```
public class MySqlDAOFactory {
private EntityManagerFactory emf;
private EntityManager em;

private static MySqlDAOFactory f;

private MySqlDAOFactory() {

Persistence.generateSchema("#persistance-Unit#", null);
  emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("#persistance-Unit#");
  em = emf.createEntityManager();
 }

 public static MySqlDAOFactory getFactory() {
  if (f == null){
   f= new MySqlDAOFactory();
                }
  return f;
 }

 public EntityDAOA getEntityDAOA() {
  return new EntityDAOAImpl(em);
 }

 public EntityDAOB getEntityDAOB() {
  return new EntityDAOBImpl(em);
 }

}
```

Then you can call this factory from your ServiceEntitiesImpl (service implementantion).

```
public class ServiceEntityImp implements ServiceEntity {

    MySqlDAOFactory f;
    EntityDAOImp edi;

    public ServiceEntityImp() {

        f = MySqlDAOFactory.getFactory();
        edi = (EntityDAOImp) f.getEntityDAO();

    }
```

Finally, your DAOs would be like:

```
public class EntityDAOImp implements EntityDAO {

    EntityManager em;

    public EntityDAOImp(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    public int insertEntity(EntityVO entity) {
        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(entity);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            return 1;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error with entity insert "+e.getMessage());
        }
        return 0;
    }

public List<EntityVO> listEntity(String entityB) {

        List<EntityVO> listByEntityB = new ArrayList<EntityVO>();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Query query = em.createQuery(
                "select distinct t from EntityVO t join fetch t.entityB b where b.entityB.name = :entityB");
        query.setParameter("entityB", entityB);
        listByEntityB = query.getResultList();
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        return listByEntityB;
    }
```

Comment: What code change in all this fixes the original problem?  Highlight/explain why your changes address the original NullPointerException, and minimize the code in your answer to make your suggested fix more easily recognizable.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as this, turns out I was just missing the mysql-connector jar in my web content area. So this needs to be reference in 2 places ...